# Autogenerate List of Links

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax

I have two tables, one for Regions and one for those regions Areas, I want to automatically create a list of links that will be like:

1. Region1
   a.Area1
   b.Area2
   c.Area3
2. Region2
   a.Area1
   etcetc

This link should be generated automatically when I load my page.
The items in the list are not only text, when I click on Area1, I will call a function passing Area1 Region1 IDs to do some action in my function, keep in mind that the user might click Area1 from Region1 or might just click Region1.

I am using asp.net 3.5 and vb.net.

Comment: Can you expand on your qusetion any?  It's hard to tell what you're getting at

Comment: I am trying generate a list of Links based on two database tables i have, one is table is for Regions, the other is for Areas.
the result should be a nested list of Regions with their Areas like i wrote before.
When i click on an item of the list, i should be be able to call a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason your question is not getting answered is that it involves too many fundamentals. if someone writes all this for you from scratch you'll have difficulty taking it any further. I would recommend looking at some ASP.NET beginners articles, work out how to write code which reacts to control events (e.g. LinkButton clicks), how to query a database, how to dynamcially populate a page etc. Then, if you have any more specific questions, ask again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i guess i wasn't clear enough in my question.
My only concern here is: how to create a dynamic bulletList-like list based on a button click, this list will be of Links